# Background process running on docker container is killed when exit VS Code

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm developing on a docker container through vscode. The container is launched in detached mode.
I have to run very long simulations and I want the process running after I close vscode. However, the process is killed while the container is still running.

Using a external terminal, I can attach the container, launch the process et detach the container. Everything is fine. The process is still running.

Can you tell me why the process stops when I launch it through vscode ?
Thanks